# TemplateSyntaxError at /allVms/ Invalid block tag: 'static'

Tags: django

I'd like to do in Django the way how to integrate css and image files using block such as static block , I wrote the html code and also its css file but when I want to display it cannot be displayed it apears on me an error.
Here below my codes

**base.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title> {% block title %} My Base Template {% endblock %} </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "assets/css/base.css"%}">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="page">
    <div id="sidebar">
    {% block sidebar %}
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/allVms">List all Servers </a></li>
    <li><a href="/FormCreateVm">Create New VM</a></li>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</htlm>
```

**base.css:**

```
body{ text-align:center;}
        #page{
            width:968px;
            text-align:left;
            margin:10px auto 20px auto;
            background-color:grey;
        }
        #sidebar{
            float:left;
            width:280px;
            border:1px solid red;
        }
        #content{
            float:left;
            width:608px;
            border:1px solid red;
            padding:18px;
        }
```

**settings.py:**

```
...
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets','/home/rochdi/Desktop/PyStack/static'),   
)
...
```

the assets is a refrence to this path from home to the static folder which contains the css and the images folders

the error is :
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before using the `static` tag, you need to load the `staticfiles` template tag library. Try adding this at the top of your template file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```